# Camera functions don't work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

I recently published an app that works perfectly on my iPhone 4, where I rely on people zooming in in the camera portion. I can zoom and turn off flash and flip the camera, but everyone else's iPhone 4 can only tap to focus and all other controls are on the screen do nothing. I am testing on iOS 5, and everyone else is using iOS 4.3.4. I haven't tested on any other iOS 5 device. Any reason those options would only work on my phone?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using iOS 5 specific functions which are not available on lower versions of iOS. Once iOS is out of NDA, perhaps someone will elaborate on why. Until then, discussion iOS 5 is a violation of your (and our) terms of use with Apple.

Comment: I built it for 4.3 and I used Xcode 4.1. I just happened to test on iOS 5

Comment: Granted, but you may still be calling methods that do not exist for older iOS versions. Check the documentation to be certain.